# What's happens when a Task continuation is scheduled on a different processor (GC logical heaps)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, task, clr

As I understand it, when the Server GC-mode is enabled for a .NET application it allocates a logical heap per processor, where threads scheduled on each processor will allocate memory to.

What happens to the memory allocated to a `Task` with multiple awaits? It could potentially be executed on any Thread from the ThreadPool, so could jump between logical heaps.

Does memory allocated on a previous logical heap get copied to the current executing logical heap? Is there any cost to not executing `Task` continuations on the same logical heap/core?

Comment: Wrong mental model.  Objects already live in different heap segments without serverGC: gen #0 through #2 and the LOH.  So more segments in serverGC is not a hangup at all.  More productive is to think that it collects garbage on more than one processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens to the memory allocated to a Task with multiple awaits? It could potentially be executed on any Thread from the ThreadPool, so could jump between logical heaps.

A thread has visibility to the entire address space, regardless of the logical separation. Heap objects can point to different objects in another heap without a boundary. Keep in mind that different threads can still be scheduled on the same CPU in different time slices.

> Does memory allocated on a previous logical heap get copied to the current executing logical heap? Is there any cost to not executing Task continuations on the same logical heap/core?

No, that would incur a tremendous run time performance hit if the runtime was forced to copy objects between heaps. Again, the fact that a thread may not run on the same logical heap that allocated it doesn't mean it can't reference that heap. The idea behind a heap per core is to be able to scale allocations and be able to imorove parallel gc collections.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Yuval, that makes sense. Could you elaborate on how this improves collection? And would the GC have to pause all threads to do a collection for a single logical heap?